# SET extra_float_digits = 3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, log

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 with my web application that has three servlets with three selects.

I turn on the log.

When I send my first query: `select * from "Nomi" limit 4`

before it the log shows me this other line:

```
execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
```

What is this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is a default setting in postgresql 8.5 onwards to guarantee recovery of higher precisions floats..

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2009-09/msg00171.php

Comment: Version 8.5 doesn't exist, it's 9.0

Comment: @Frank: http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1152/ I think 8.5 might be a dev version (here is the relevant commit for this change http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2009-09/msg00180.php), I am not too sure about the versioning though..